# Meteor and Google Place Autocomplete - InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

Tags: html, meteor, autocomplete

I'm looking to use Google Place Autocomplete on one of my Meteor App Input.

When I initialize a session, I have an **InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement**, but when I refresh the page one time, the autocomplete works well.

What do I need to change on my code in order to have autocomplete working on first session?

My code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    window.onload = function() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{types:['geocode']}
    );
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed',function(){
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    });
  };
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Call below code on-focus of input element.

```
 var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
  (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{types:['geocode']}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Template instance:

```
Template.autocomplete.onRendered(function() {
    // Your autocomplete function
    // var autocomplete = ...
});
```

My template name is "autocomplete" in this example.